# How to determine if a node has more than one input in a graph data structure?

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to create a simple network for Strings modulation.
[image: Network of modules]

The idea is the output of the network is the output of the last executed module.
Modules can be arranged in any way and if a module has to connections as an input, the input should be summed (strings concatenation).

To implement it, I'm thinking to represent the network as a graph data structure.

What is blocking me right now is how to determine that module has two connections as the input (so I will be able to sum the two outputs before feeding the result as the input)?

What algorithm to use to traverse the graph? breadth-first?

Any better solution to represent the network?
[pseudo code is highly appreciated]

Comment: I think if you traverse the graph in both directions you should model it bidirectional, with inputs and outputs. In fact when your default case is backwards tracking the import references are the backreferences, you could do with only these and drop the Input->Output references completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing the graph as an adjacency list ("This node points to these nodes"), then you can simply iterate over the adjacency list and swap the A -> B pairs to B -> A, creating an inverse adjacency list ("This node is pointed to by these nodes").

More info in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

EDIT:

From your diagram, the adjacency list would be:

```
A -> [B, C]
B -> [D]
C -> [D]
D -> []
```

This can be represented as a `Map<Node, Collection<Node>>`. Write a method that takes a pair and updates the map, call it `connect`. To build the structure you would call it with `connect(A, B)`, `connect(A, C)`, `connect(B, D)`, `connect(C, D)`.

To invert it, create a new Map to hold inverted structure. Iterate over each key in the map, and then over each value in the list, and call `connect` on the inverted structure with the arguments reversed.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following. This is my original adjacency list: [[A B -> C -> D] [B D] [C D]]. What is the reversed adjacency list? After getting the reversed list, what to do? what traversing algorithm to use? I'm sorry but the concept is a some how complicated to me.

Comment: ...resulting in [A->[], B->[A], C->[A], D->[B,C]]. Each node pointing to its inputs. A has node, B and C have A as input, and D has 2, which need to be concatenated.

Comment: Yep. Do you you think I need to include that? I thought it might be obvious. Perhaps not.

Comment: Graphs (nodes and edges) are a fascinating subject in computer science. They apply to a lot of seemingly different subjects. Give them a read, there's more magic to be discovered!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this both in a breadth-first, and depth-first. I am gonna post a depth-first algorithm:

```
public class Node {

    private List<Node> parents = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private Map<Node, String> receivedMessages = new HashMap<Node, String>();
    private String id = "";

    public Node(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    void processMessage(Node sender, String message) {
        if (parents.contains(sender))
            receivedMessages.put(sender, message);

        // if all the parents sent the message
        if (receivedMessages.size() == parents.size()) {
            String newMessage = composeNewMessage(receivedMessages);

            if (children.size() == 0) // if end node or "leaf"
                ouputResult(this, newMessage);
            else {
                for (Node child : children) {
                    child.processMessage(this, newMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void addParent(Node parent) {
        if (parent != null)
            parents.add(parent);
        parent.children.add(this);
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        if (child != null)
            children.add(child);
        child.parents.add(this);
    }

    private void ouputResult(Node node, String newMessage) {
        // TODO: implement
    }

    private String composeNewMessage(Map<Node, String> receivedMessages2) {
        // TODO: implement
        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node A = new Node("A");
        Node B = new Node("B");
        Node C = new Node("C");
        Node D = new Node("D");
        Node start = new Node("start");
        Node end = new Node("end");
        A.addParent(start);
        B.addParent(A);
        C.addParent(A);
        D.addParent(B);
        D.addParent(C);
        end.addParent(D);
        A.processMessage(start, "Message");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess composeNewMessage() method doesn't need a parameter since it can access receivedMessages instance variable.

Comment: yes.. sure. You said you wanted pseudo code, I put it so for clarification (composeNewMessage uses the receivedMessages). Remove it if code quality is of concert to you.

Comment: How can I get ride of start and end nodes?